# Sum of multiple select count distinct with case function

Tags: sql, select, group-by, count

I try to make a sum of multiple select count distinct with case function. For example:

```
SELECT id_dept, 
       count(DISTINCT case when e.statut='pub'  then id_patients end) AS nb_patients_pub,
       count(DISTINCT case when e.statut='priv' then id_patients end) AS nb_patients_priv
FROM venues
```

I would like to make of these two results in only one columns.
Is it possible?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want `in`:

```
SELECT 
    id_dept, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN e.statut IN ('pub', 'priv') THEN id_patients END) AS nb_patients_pub_and_venues
FROM venues
GROUP BY id_dept
```

Note that I added a `GROUP BY` clause to the query, which was initially missing (this is a syntax error in almost all databases).

Depending on your data, this might not do exactly what you want; if a given `id_patient` has both statuses, then it will be counted only once, whereas your code counted it once in each `count(distinct ...)`. If so, then you can just keep the two separated counts, and sum them:

```
SELECT 
    id_dept, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN e.statut IN = 'pub' THEN id_patients END) 
        + COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN e.statut IN = 'priv' THEN id_patients END) 
        AS nb_patients_pub_and_venues
FROM venues
GROUP BY id_dept
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with current code, then either sum (using `+`) those `count`s, or use that query as a CTE (or an inline view) and

```
with test as
  (SELECT id_dept, 
       count(DISTINCT case when e.statut='pub'  then id_patients end) 
         AS nb_patients_pub,
       count(DISTINCT case when e.statut='priv' then id_patients end) 
         AS nb_patients_priv
   FROM venues
   GROUP BY id_dept
  )   
select id, nb_patients_pub + nb_patients_priv as result
from test;
```